# Select appropriate date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a first table T1 with a date and some other informations:

```
--TABLE1
date, field1, field2, field3...
20120801 | info1    | info2    | ...
20120802 | info1    | info2    | ...
20120803 | info1    | info2    | ...
20120804 | info1    | info2    | ...
20120805 | info1    | info2    | ...
20120806 | info1    | info2    | ...
```

I have a second table T2 which contains date related informations, with business days and weekend days:

```
--TABLE2
date, businessdayofthemonth, day, field4...
20120801 | 1    | Wednesday | ...
20120802 | 2    | Thursday  | ...
20120803 | 3    | Friday    | ...
20120804 | NULL | Saturday  | ...
20120805 | NULL | Sunday    | ...
20120806 | 4    | Lundi     | ...
```

Now what I am trying to do:
I want to have for every line of table 1, the date of table 2 which is exactly corresponding to the 3rd business day after a given date <=> (isnumeric(businessdayofthemonth)=1)

for instance if i select the first line of T1:

```
dateT1   | dateT1+3 | TheDateIWant |
20120801 | 20120804 | 20120806     | info1 | info2 | ...
```

Hope I explained it correctly , thank you

**EDIT:**
I think i didn't explain this right: I need the date that is exactly 3 business days after a given date which means:

for:

```
20120803 | 3    | Friday    | ...
```

i want the next 3 business days date:

```
20120808
```

btw why downvote? i work on a database with litteraly billions of rows, this is only part of the work i do on a 300 lines request over 15 tables, if i post, i tried.

Comment: The closest business date to `20120804` is `20120803`, not `20120806`. Do you mean the closest date *on or after* the given date?

Comment: yes i need the next date that is exactly 3 business days after

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2, I am actually wondering if what i ask is  even possible..

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
select t1.date, t1.field1, t1.field2,
    (
        select top 1 date
        from Table2 t2
        where businessdayofthemonth is not null
        order by abs((t1.Date + 3) - t2.Date)
    ) as T2_Date
from Table1 t1
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88fb0/8)

Note this will give you the closest date on, before, or after `Table1.Date + 3`. If you only want dates on or after, you can do:

```
select t1.date, t1.field1, t1.field2,
    (
        select top 1 date
        from Table2 t2
        where businessdayofthemonth is not null
            and t2.Date >= (t1.Date + 3)
        order by t2.Date - (t1.Date + 3)
    ) as T2_Date
from Table1 t1
```

Comment: I was thinking this too, but what happens at the end of the month?

Comment: @davehale23 I don't understand your question. Can you be more specific?

Comment: when the `date` gets to be 20120831 then you are now searching for 20120834 in the second table.  What I'm getting at is that this seems very difficult to do if the `date` fields are integers.

Comment: on sql server when you use DATEADD(DAY, 3, D.DateValeur) it works. Now i edited my question, and i dont think this will do the trick, ty for the help anyway

Comment: @davehale23 I assumed the dates were of type `datetime`. If they are integers, this is indeed a problem, and the dates will need to be converted first.

Comment: they are datetime, but still your answer helps but isnt correct during the weekend :-(

Comment: @Kingpin It is correct for the question as originally stated. You are now asking a new question.

Comment: @RedFilter yes, i edited it, your answer was correct but i still need help